# Using of ternary operator in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ternary-operator

I just want to use [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) in a view:

```
 <input type="password" ng-model="password" />
 {{ ( password == "qwerty") ? 'PASSED' : 'NOT PASSED' }}
```

But it throws error:

> Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 25-25 [?] in
>   expression [ ( password == "qwerty") ? 'PASSED' : 'NOT PASSED' ].

I know i can solve it with controller or with something like `['true':'PASSED','false':'NOT PASSED'][(password == "qwerty")]` but what is the problem with the '`?`'?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/KAgrw/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use angular 1.1.5+/1.2+.  Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: aah , 1.1.4 , i'll try now to update and see if it not destroying my app

Comment: great , upgrade was painless :D

Answer (score 4):

If you plan to use ternary operations in angular, you can do it by changing your syntax from

```
{{exp ? true : false}}
```

to

```
{{exp && '<value for true>' || '<value for false'}}
```

example:

```
<div> Total: {{bill.total == 0 && 'test' || 'test2' }} </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KAgrw/9/

Fixed my fiddle :D

Comment: very nice and elegant

Comment: Thank you. Was an intredasting question :) had to explore this one. 

Added fiddle to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you have illegal characters in

```
{{ ( password == "qwerty") ? 'PASSED` : `NOT PASSED` }}
```

instead of ` you should use '